# What are natural malefic planets?

Tags: scripture, astrology, navagraha

There are some planets in Astrology that are believed to be natural malefic. I do not know the names and I believe that Rahu and Sani are natural malefics.

Is the concept of *natural malefic planets* true?

Comment: Brihat Parashara 3.11 says: तत्रार्कशनिभूपुत्राः क्षीणेन्दुराहुकेतवः। क्रूराः शेषग्रहा सौम्याः क्रूरः क्रूरयुतो बुधः॥११॥ - Surya, Shani, mangala, Chandra in krishna paksha (waning/ reducing moon), Rahu and Ketu are malefic. The rest are benefics except Budha which when in conjunction with a malefic is also a malefic. So yes the concept of natural malefic exists. Benefic = Guru, Shukra, Budha (except above) and Chandra in Shukla Paksha. I don’t have more knowledge but, Swapnil will be able to give a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sun, Mars, Saturn are considered as natural malefics along with Rahu and Ketu.

The text [Hora Ratnam](https://www.astrojyoti.com/horaratnam-chapter-one-6.htm) talks about what the different authorities say on the topic:

> 117. Qualities of Planets: Based on Hora Makaranda, malefic planets are Mars, the Sun, Saturn and the weak Moon. Mercury in the company of
>      these planets will also be a malefic. Full Moon, Jupiter and Venus are
>      benefics. If Mercury joins a benefic planet, he will be a benefic.
>      Mercury is a malefic only when he is with one of the Sun, Mars and
>      Saturn, but not when with the weak Moon.
>
> Notes: The work quoted here does not however specifically bring
> Mercury in the category of independent benefics. It must be
> understood, Mercury if alone is” also a benefic. However his joining a
> weak Moon does not turn him into a malefic. Kalyana Varma clearly
> states this as under.
>
> 118. As per Kalyana Varma: Jupiter, Mercury and Venus are benefics. Saturn, Mars ‘and the Sun are natural malefics. The weak Moon and
>      Mercury in the company of, a malefic are malefics.
>
> Bala Bhadra’ Clarifies: In case of calculations related to life-span,
> the Moon in the ascendant is treated to be weak from the 13th day of
> dark fortnight through the 2nd, day of bright fortnight (i.e. for a
> period of 5 days). Hence Yavanesvara treats the weak Moon as a
> malefic. ‘
>
> Notes: According to Brihat Parasara Hora Sastra, ch. 43, sloka 11, the
> Moon though weak is never a malefic for purpose of life-span
> calculations. This is more authoritative a statement than that of
> Yavanas quoted by Bala Bhadra bright half through.the 5th day of dark
> lunar half, the Moon is Full (i.e. strong and is known as Poorna
> Chandra), and from the 6th day of dark lunar half through Amavasya
> (New Moon day and is known Ksheena Chandra), it is of feeble strength.
>
> (b) Exception: When aspected by a benefic, the Moon is invariably
> strong.
>
> (c) Malefic planets are the Sun, Mars, and Saturn. Benefic planets are
> Venus, Mercury and Jupiter. With a benefic, Mercury remains a benefic
> and in the company of a malefic (except with weak Moon as already
> pointed of it), he turns malefic.
>
> 121. Sage Vasishta on Nodes: In respect of all undertakings, malefic planets are the Sun, Mars, Saturn, Rahu, Ketu and the weak Moon. Full
>      Moon, Jupiter, Venus and Mercury are .benefic planets. .

So, apart from the ones I mentioned at the start, a weak moon is also regarded as a natural malefic by some authorities.